# Asynchronous Programming in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have to do asynchronous programming in windows application (.net 3.5 C#) by doing long processes in background and showing user a progress form on User Interface. How can I do this windows based application

Comment: Sorry to tell you that [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505). We need to see what you have tried, your current code and a good explanation of where you are stuck before we can help.

Comment: It's not asynchronous programming, it's concurrent programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class:

Answer (score 6):

Check [Asynchronous Programming design pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2009/04/11/asynchronous-delegates-and-calback.aspx), [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.90%29), [Event Based Async Pattern](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Event-Based_Asynchronous_Pattern), [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern Overview msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx), and  [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you let your long processes run asynchronously in separate threads and notify the UI thread. If you want more details, you'll need to supply more details and some code.